# sometimes I don't want to be forced to interact with the topmost window. How can I get around it, without closing it?

Tags: windows-7

We've all seen this when we opened a setting or preference window from a context menu in a program we're using-- the window flashes/flickers and forces you to close it if you want to get at information 'below' it in the z-order window stack.

What is this 'feature' called?

Is there a way to prevent Windows from forcing interaction?

Comment: Are you talking about a modal dialog? If so, this is by design! It means the developer of the software has purposely chosen this and they don't want you to interact with the rest of the application until you've finished using the dialog.

Comment: Bennnn, your comments are childish and unfounded. I use Modal Dialogs a lot when developing - it is there for a reason. Some times, I don't want users to change things or click on things because by doing so could, as example, mean I write incorrect config data which would then break the app! This is surely more obstructive to usability! One could argue the developer could find another approach but, it's there for a reason and will be used! Disable it at your own risk (via the dupe I cited)

Comment: yes, good design that requires filling in the modal dialog with information you must get from memory or by closing it first (Android Studio).

Comment: the dupe you cited is for focus stealing not focus demanding.